# Merging matrices into each other in R

Tags: r, matrix

I'm trying to merge two equally large matrices into each other such that it takes column 1 from matrix 1 and then column 1 from matrix 2, then column 2 from matrix 1 then column 2 from matrix 2 and so on.

I've tried with the followin code:

```
for (i in 1:ncol(M1){M3<-cbind(M1[,1:i],M2[,1:i])}
```

but this just merges the two matrices with M2 following the data of M1 and not intertwining them-

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please post a mini example of your data sets and the desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the code you were trying to write looks like this:

```
for (i in 1:ncol(M1){M3<-cbind(M3, M1[,i],M2[,i])}
```

However, iterative cbind-ing really isn't good practise within R
You might be better to do:

```
M3 <- cbind(M1, M2)
M3 <- M3[, rep(1:ncol(M1), each=2) + rep(c(0,ncol(M1)), ncol(M1))]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try 
`matrix(rbind(M1,M2),nrow(M1),ncol(M1)+ncol(M2))`

The trick is that `R` processes matrices column by column. Don't waste your time on `for`-loops.